# Update mdf file with ldf

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to have an old copy of a `.mdf` file with an up-to-date `.ldf` file and update the `.mdf` file from the latest transaction logs?

Comment: no not from the logs; did you mean log backups?

Comment: so, I have a backup of the transaction logs (the ldf file) which is up to date, however the mdf file is a couple of days old. is there a way to mount the mdf file and update the changes that were made with the mdf file transactions?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as I've never attempted that; in theory if you have the log backup starting at the correct LSN, It should be possible.

Comment: You _should_ be able to, take a look here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c1f7d5/how-to-recover-deleted-and-drop-data-and-tables-in-sql-serve/ this is using the LDF to restore up to a delete, but the principles are the same.

Comment: You should rather ask at dba.stackexchange.com